# Convert String to Timestamp Java

Tags: java, timestamp, parseexception

So I am having this issue that I can't wrap my head around. I've read similar questions posed but very case I've found there is an issue with the format, and my format is correct.

Basically I am trying to convert a String into a Timestamp, and I get the unparseable date error.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public class Hello {

public static Timestamp convertStringToTimestamp(String str_date) {
    try {

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS");
        Date date = formatter.parse(str_date);
        java.sql.Timestamp timeStampDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        return timeStampDate;

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception :" + e);
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timestamp ts = convertStringToTimestamp("2015-06-09 11:51:12,708");
    Timestamp ts2 = convertStringToTimestamp("2015-04-17 11:29:49.564");
    System.out.println(ts +" | "+ts2);


}

}
```

Output:

```
Exception :java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-06-09 11:51:12,708"
Exception :java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-04-17 11:29:49.564"
null | null
```

Any ideas?

Comment: yes, you have `,` in your date format, and in your date string you have `.` try change this, and it should work

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for the first date in my machine... Are you using a custom JRE or something???

Comment: JavaSE-1.8
is this wrong?

Comment: are you sure it is right code? try to rebuild it and run again, it looks like you are running old code

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
**Update**
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class SomeClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


         System.out.println(convertStringToTimestamp("2015-06-09 11:51:12,708"));
         //be consistent here with , and .
         System.out.println(convertStringToTimestamp("2015-04-17 11:29:49.564"));
         System.out.println();


    }

    private static Timestamp  convertStringToTimestamp(String something) {


SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = null;
        if(something.contains(".")) {
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
        } 
        if(something.contains(",")) {
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss,SSS");
        }
        Timestamp timestamp = null;
            Date parsedDate;
            try {
                parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(something);
                 timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return timestamp;
    }



}
```

Comment: @Jesper it solves the problem with this "Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());" is it so difficult to understand ?

Comment: But this is not different from what the OP already posted. (Carefully look at the code in the question).

Comment: So this works if you input the pattern directly into the dateFormat.parse()
However, with your solution, and trying to fit the inputted string still returns the parseException, disregarding of ',' or '.' (comma dot)

Comment: @jensd I have updated the code ... this code should work you have to be more consistent with ',' and '.' because at format we are specifying ','

Comment: Yes this works, also some other submitted examples works as well. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome mate ... made last edits if you still want to use ',' and '.' ;)

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly to me.

I just passed the right **pattern** as an **input** as well.

```
public static Timestamp convertStringToTimestamp(String str_date, String pattern) {
        try {

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            Date date = formatter.parse(str_date);
            java.sql.Timestamp timeStampDate = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
            return timeStampDate;

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception :" + e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timestamp ts = convertStringToTimestamp("2015-06-09 11:51:12,708", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS");
        Timestamp ts2 = convertStringToTimestamp("2015-04-17 11:29:49.564", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        System.out.println(ts +" | "+ts2);


    }
```

The output is:

```
2015-06-09 11:51:12.708 | 2015-04-17 11:29:49.564
```

Comment: Yes this works, however it is troublesome to pass the formatter as argument, but I understand why you did it due to my comma/dot implementation.
Thanks!

Comment: Since there's 2 kinds of patterns I follow this approach. Hope that helps. :-)

Comment: If it helps, please, check it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

"﻿2015-06-09 11:51:12,708" is working for me but "﻿2015-04-17 11:29:49.564" won't. You specified the regex for "," so "." would not. It is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0):

you need to fix the comma

```
Timestamp ts2 = convertStringToTimestamp("2015-04-17 11:29:49.564");
```